# R tilde operator: What does ~0+a means?

Tags: r

I have seen how to use ~ operator in formula. For example `y~x` means: y is distributed as x.

However I am really confused of what does `~0+a` means in this code:

```
require(limma)
a = factor(1:3)
model.matrix(~0+a)
```

Why just `model.matrix(a)` does not work? Why the result of `model.matrix(~a)` is different from `model.matrix(~0+a)`? And finally what is the meaning of ~ operator here?

Comment: Given your self-answer, I would argue that this is not an `R` specific question, but a more general question on linear models and formula symbology.

Comment: If you have access to it, you might want to look at the paper defining this notation: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346786 (by Wilkinson and Rogers, hence this notation is often called "Wilkinson-Rogers notation"

Comment: @mnel: this is the R specific notation to take ~a-1 as no-intercept formula. I am just resolving a problem in understanding R formula I faced for a long time.

Comment: @BenBolker - thanks for the link, I knew there was a paper defining the notation, but couldn't find it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`~` creates a formula - it separates the righthand and lefthand sides of a formula

From `` ?`~` ``

> Tilde is used to separate the left- and right-hand sides in model formula

Quoting from the help for formula

> The models fit by, e.g., the lm and glm functions are specified in a compact symbolic form. The ~ operator is basic in the formation of such models. An expression of the form y ~ model is interpreted as a specification that the response y is modelled by a linear predictor specified symbolically by model. Such a model consists of a series of terms separated by + operators. The terms themselves consist of variable and factor names separated by : operators. Such a term is interpreted as the interaction of all the variables and factors appearing in the term.
>
> In addition to + and :, a number of other operators are useful in model formulae. The * operator denotes factor crossing: a*b interpreted as a+b+a:b. The ^ operator indicates crossing to the specified degree. For example (a+b+c)^2 is identical to (a+b+c)*(a+b+c) which in turn expands to a formula containing the main effects for a, b and c together with their second-order interactions. The %in% operator indicates that the terms on its left are nested within those on the right. For example a + b %in% a expands to the formula a + a:b. The - operator removes the specified terms, so that (a+b+c)^2 - a:b is identical to a + b + c + b:c + a:c. It can also used to remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model y ~ x - 1 specifies a line through the origin. A model with no intercept can be also specified as y ~ x + 0 or y ~ 0 + x.

#### So regarding specific issue with `~a+0`

- You creating a model matrix without an intercept. As `a` is a factor, `model.matrix(~a)` will return an intercept column which is `a1` (You need `n-1` indicators to fully specify `n` classes)

The help files for each function are well written, detailed and easy to find!

## why doesn't `model.matrix(a)` work

`model.matrix(a)` doesn't work because `a` is a `factor` variable, not a formula or terms object

From the help for `model.matrix`

> **object**     an object of an appropriate class. For the default method, a
>   model formula or a terms object.

`R` is looking for a particular class of object, by passing a formula `~a` you are passing an object that is of class `formula`. `model.matrix(terms(~a))` would also work, (passing the terms object corresponding to the formula `~a`

---

#### general note

@BenBolker helpfully notes in his comment, This is a modified version of Wilkinson-Rogers notation.

There is a good description in [the Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models).

Answer (score 6):

After reading several manuals, I was confused by the meaning of `model.matrix(~0+x)` ountil recently that I found [this excellent book chapter](http://users.monash.edu.au/~murray/stats/BIO4200/LinearModels.pdf).

In mathematics `0+a` is equal to `a` and writing a term like `0+a` is very strange. However we are here dealing with linear models: A simple high-school equation such as `y=ax+b` that uncovers the relationship between the predictor variable (x) and the observation (y).

So we can think of `~0+x` or equally `~x+0` as an equation of the form: `y=ax+b`. By adding `0` we are forcing `b` to be zero, that means that we are looking for a line passing the origin (no intercept). If we indicated a model like `~x+1` or just `~x`, there fitted equation could possibily contain a non-zero term `b`. Equally we may restrict `b` by a formula `~x-1` or `~-1+x` that both mean: no intercept (the same way we exclude a row or column in R by negative index). However something like `~x-2` or `~x+3` is meaningless.

Thanking @mnel for the useful comment, finally what's the reason to use `~` and not `=`? In standard mathematical terminology / symbology `y~x` denotes that y is equivalent to x, it is somewhat weaker that `y=x`. When you are fitting a linear model, you aren't really saying `y=x`, but more that you can model y as a linear function of x (`y = ax+b` for example)

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question, tilde is used to separate the left- and right-hand sides in model formula. See `?"~"` for more help.